# php and mssql/sqlsrv - column names containing question marks instead of accented characters

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8

I'm trying to dump some reports to HTML from a MSSQL 2005 database, but there is a slight problem when trying to display column *names* (not the column data itself, that's displaying properly) that have accented characters in them - they are replaced by question marks instead.

I'm using the sqlsrv driver for PHP, running under IIS7. PHP script itself is UTF-8 encoded. I'm connecting to the SQL server as:

```
  $connection_info = array("Database" => "ProjectManager", "UID" => DB_USER, "PWD" => DB_PASS , "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect(DB_HOST, $connection_info) or die("FAIL");
```

The first thing after running the query is dumping column names into a table:

```
$qry = "EXEC [dbo].[dummy_report] @year=2012, @month=3";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qry);
foreach(sqlsrv_field_metadata($res) as $fieldData) {
    echo "<th>".$fieldData['Name']."</th>";
}
```

This handles data stored in the database well enough; column names - not so much:

[image]

Normally, I wouldn't go about naming database columns in Slovak, but I'm just trying to display the result of a stored procedure and I'm not really comfortable hardcoding those field names into the PHP script.

So, charsets. Wat do?

Comment: Do you have the CharacterSet set to UTF-8 in driver_options? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, it's specified in the $connection_info array in the OP (it's guarded from prying eyes by a horizontal scrollbar).

Comment: "column names containing ... accented characters" OH GOD. *runs like the wind*

Comment: Yeah, I know >_> I did a few hours of looking for directions/RTFM, but that didn't turn anything up (maybe for reasons obvious), so I thought I'd ask here. I'll probably harcode it in tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem as you did. And after a lot of googling, it turns to be a BUG of "Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server".

See more info here:[PHP sqlsrv 3.0.1 Driver: sqlsrv_field_metadata returns column name as char*, so unicode column names can't be fetched correctly](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/workitem/22417).